# Kafka consumer commit thread-safety

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I am using [Confluent.Kafka](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet) dotnet client.

```
namespace Confluent.Kafka
{
    public class Consumer<TKey, TValue> : IDisposable
    {
         public Task<CommittedOffsets> CommitAsync();
    }
}
```

As you see, Consumer.CommitAsync is an async method.   Is it safe to call `CommitAsync` method without waiting its response and then make the next call to `Subscribe`?

Example code below.

```
using (var consumer = new Confluent.Kafka.Consumer<MessageKey, byte[]>(config, new MessageKeyDeserializer(), new ByteArrayDeserializer()))
{
                consumer.Subscribe(topics);

                while (true)
                {
                    Message<MessageKey, byte[]> msg;
                    if (consumer.Consume(out msg, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
                    {
                        // ...

                        if( msg.Offset % 100 == 0)
                        {
                            consumer.CommitAsync().ContinueWith((t) =>
                           {
                               // log t.Exception
                           }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
                        }
                    }
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you wanted to say next call to Consume

Yes, it is safe, no problem with this.
I would also add some time window for commit (what come first between 5s and 100msgs for example) so that if you don't receive messages for some time you still commit them